# AmazonDynamoDBException: User: username is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:DescribeTable on resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to use spring boot with spring cloud steam binder kinesis to connect to Amazon firehose to read data from fireshose stream.
I am getting following exception and not sure why it is trying to see in dynamodb.

> Caused by:
>   com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: User:
>   arn:aws:iam::accountId:user/emailid is not authorized to perform:
>   dynamodb:DescribeTable on  resource:
>   arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:265878766430:table/SpringIntegrationMetadataStore
>   (Service:  AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
>   AccessDeniedException; Request ID: 
>   requestidnumber)

I could connect to same firehose stream using the same credentials by python firehose library. But not with the spring cloud stream binder kinesis

Comment: I think this requires a creation of Role and Policy allowing the user to access the dynamodb table. Can you clarify if these are in place?

Answer (score -1):

The issue is related to Dynamodb access and privileges.

AWS keys should have permissions for DynamoDB.
Spring cloud steam binder kinesis tries to create SpringIntegrationLockRegistry  in Dynamodb.

If access to and privileges to Dynamodb are not present then, we enter into these kind of issues.

The issues i have encountered during application set up are

1. Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: User: 
   arn:aws:iam::someid:user/username is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:DescribeTable 
   on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:region:id:table/SpringIntegrationMetadataStore (Service: 
   AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: 
   requestid

2. a.i.k.KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter : Error during locking: DynamoDbLock [lockKey=anonymous.someid:streamName:shardId-number,lockedAt=2020-03-27@10:22:38.129, lockItem=null]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The DynamoDb table SpringIntegrationLockRegistry has not been created during 60 seconds